# STL algorithm function name resolution

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces

I'd expect in the example bellow compiler will fail to compile the code, since it
doesn't know what is "find()", which defined in *std* namespace in *algorithm* header.

However this code compiles on RHEL 5.3 with gcc 4.1.2.

What do I miss?

```
#include <string>    
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    find(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');  // should not compile
}
```

Comment: @Nick: Neither. See the answer below.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276772/why-was-argument-dependent-lookup-invented and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60bx1ys7.aspx.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This works due to Argument Dependent Lookup. The function-template is searched in the namespace of the arguments types. In this case, the arguments are `std::string::iterator`, so the function is searched in the namespace `std`.

Comment: +1 — ADL begins to make more sense in some contexts: Extending boost::hash_value, for example, can be done using ADL.

Comment: Aka Koenig lookup.  dimba: if you want to prove this to yourself, you can see that `::find` won't get a match in the global namespace, and given `char a[1]`, `find(&a[0], &a[0], 'a')` won't find the `std::find() template`....

Comment: Just to elaborate on *why* ADL exists, the "primary" justification for ADL is so that operators work naturally. given two `std::string` objects `s1` and `s2`, you want to be able to concatenate them with `s1 + s2`. Without ADL, you'd have to write `std::operator+(s1, s2)`. But it has turned out to be a very useful mechanism for other cases as well

Comment: Another good example for how ADL can be used to customize the Standard Library is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap/2684544#2684544).

Comment: @jalf: Is that example really sound? As far as I can see (which isn't very far tonight - got to stop playing stupid games until 4am), a global `::operator+(const std::string&, const std::string&)` could be matched anyway.  So, it's more about finding the right `find()` despite other unrelated `find()`s in intervening namespaces associated with the calling code....

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I met this behavior a couple of years ago. I was not compiling using `-ansi` and "thus" able to access STL types without prefixing with `std`. Would you mind having a look at my [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990898/how-to-overload-the-ostream-operator-to-make-it-work-with-log4cxx-in-c)?

Comment: @mister: Sorry, but I cannot help you there.

Comment: @Tony: but then they'd have to put standard library components outside of the `std` namespace, which would make the namespace pretty pointless.

Comment: @jalf: not really - the names of the function parameter types - including their use of `std::` - partake in the formation of the overall linker symbol anyway, so such a global function's still safe from clashes....

Comment: @Tony: True, but my point was simply that the standard library is otherwise consistent about placing everything in a `std` namespace. Suddenly deciding that "hey, let's put all the operator overloads in the global namespace" would seem very inconsistent, and, with modern IDE's offering intellisense and autocompletion, would clutter up the global namespace needlessly.

Comment: Keep in mind also that the standard prohibits users from adding or modifying anything in namespace `std` (with an exception made specifically for template specializations for user-defined types). Putting standard library components outside that namespace would needlessly complicate that issue. Yes, they could have worked around the operator problem without adding ADL, but it would have been a messy, inconsistent and misleading hack, and it would have prevented users from doing what seems intuitive (putting the operators next to the class they operate on)